# Micropayment.de Testing

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway

I have implemented **call2pay** event API for **micropayment.de** but I don't know how to test it. Does it provide any testing environment like Paypal (Sandbox)?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently each function has an optional parameter named `testmode` which can set to `1` to activate the sandbox. You can simulate a call with the [testcall function](http://techdoc.micropayment.de/payment/call2pay_api_event/call2pay_api_event_2.0_en.html#id494716).

Comment: I could not find how to get the accesskey for the test call

Comment: I have found the accesskey but now I am not able to find the sessionid. If you have idea regarding it please help me.

Comment: you get the sessionId from the sessionCreate call.